# sql.eachRow only adds the last record into a list

Tags: sql, list, groovy

Good day, I'm trying to add all the users from my db to a list and print it out in a frame. But the problem is that I am only retrieving the LAST record of the users table. The others are being ignored. Here's my code

```
   table(selectionMode: ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION){
                     sql.eachRow("select * from users"){row->
                          println row;
                        def staffList = []    
               staffList.add(uname:row.uname,pwd:row.pwd);

                    tableModel(list : staffList){
                   closureColumn(header:'Username',read:{row1 -> return row1.uname})
                   closureColumn(header:'Password',read:{row1 -> return row1.pwd})


                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have redefined the staffList array within the loop. Move that to before, and you may have better results.

Comment: Hello, @Steve Lovell! Thank you so much! It did work. So every closure is a loop. I'm sorry because I'm such a newbie here in Groovy. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. If you could mark that as the answer, that would be lovely.